# Question - How do I pass "RegExp Object ?? in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Regarding page.evaluate method...

I want to use "replace" method. But I can not pass RegExp objects....

example)

```
const result = await page.evaluate(x => {
return Promise.resolve(8 * x);
}, 7);
console.log(result); // prints "56" <=SUCCESS!!

const result = await page.evaluate(x => {
const a = "apple"
return Promise.resolve(a.replace(x, "banana"));
}, "apple");
console.log(result); // prints "banana" <=SUCCESS!!

const result = await page.evaluate(x => {
const a = "apple"
return Promise.resolve(a.replace(x, "banana"));
}, /apple/);
console.log(result); // prints "apple" <= failure...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate from source using [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp):

```js
const result = await page.evaluate((pattern, flags) => {
  const x = RegExp(pattern, flags);
  const a = "apple";
  return Promise.resolve(a.replace(x, "banana"));
}, 'apple', 'i' );
console.log(result);
```